# Python iterate through txt file of dates and change date format

Tags: python-2.7, loops, datetime

I have a txt file oldDates.txt. I want to loop through it, modify the date formats and write the newly formatted dates to a new txt file. My code so far:

```
from datetime import datetime

f = open('oldDates.txt', r)
oldDates = []
newDates = []

for line in f.readlines():
    oldDates.append(line)
    print(line) # for testing

for oldDate in oldDates:
    dt = datetime.strptime(oldDate, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    newDates.append(dt)

with open('newDates.txt', 'w') as w:
    for newDate in newDates:
        w.write(newDate+"\n")

f.close()
w.close()
```

However, this give an error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here, and if there's a more efficient way of doing this then I'd be glad to hear about it. The date conversion seems to work fine from the test print.

There are blank lines in the file and I'm wondering if I need to handle these (I'm not sure how).

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Now, I am no expert in Python, but do you verify your input to be the correct format ? If you apply a regexp on the input line you can easily catch blank lines and any incorrect values.

Comment: I suspect there's an easier way of doing this without turning to RegEx which I'd wanted to avoid. I think it's blank lines causing the issue and I suspect there's an easier way of handling them. I still want to keep the blank lines as blank lines.

Comment: If the line is blank, and you know the format is otherwise ok, how about checking for line length ? It's simple and fast. If length is < date length, just add blank to output.  I would do that, although in a different language of choice.

Comment: Some of the dates are like this 3/8/2001, or 18/3/2010.
I'm trying to output them as DD/MM/YYYY with leading zeroes as needed.
I seem to be getting the error I mentioned running my code. I don't think I need to check line lengths do I?